# How can I add a namespace xmlns:xyz to an xml document using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML:

```
<Root>
 <Name>Eding</Name>
 <Roll>15</Roll>
 <xyz:Address>25, Brigton,SA</xyz:Address>
</Root>
```

This xml is not valid as the namespace `xyz` is not defined. So, I want to add the namespace in the root using xslt.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

XSLT will only take namespace-well-formed XML as input. So if your input isn't namespace-well-formed, you can't solve the problem with XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is through the use of an [external (parsed) general entity](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-external-ent).

**You could "wrap" the invalid XML file with an XML document that declares the `xyz` namespace-prefix and then includes the content of your file using an external entity.** Then transform the file to remove the wrapped content and produce the desired output.

For this example, your example file is referred to as `fragment.xml`. I defined an external entity pointing to the file and then reference it inside of the `wrapper` element. The `wrapper` element has the `xyz` namespace prefix defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE wrapper [
<!ENTITY otherFile SYSTEM "fragment.xml">
]>
<wrapper xmlns:xyz="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024763/how-can-i-add-a-namespace-xmlnsxyz-to-an-xml-document-using-xslt">
&otherFile;
</wrapper>
```

**When parsed by any XML parser, the document will be "seen" as:**

```
<wrapper xmlns:xyz="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024763/how-can-i-add-a-namespace-xmlnsxyz-to-an-xml-document-using-xslt">
<Root>
    <Name>Eding</Name>
    <Roll>15</Roll>
    <xyz:Address>25, Brigton,SA</xyz:Address>
</Root>
</wrapper>
```

**Then, use a modified [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) with a template to remove the `wrapper` element:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="1.0">

    <!--identity template to copy all content forward by default -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--remove the "wrapper" element, then process the rest of the content -->
    <xsl:template match="/wrapper">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Producing the following output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xyz="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024763/how-can-i-add-a-namespace-xmlnsxyz-to-an-xml-document-using-xslt">
    <Name>Eding</Name>
    <Roll>15</Roll>
    <xyz:Address>25, Brigton,SA</xyz:Address>
</Root>
```